# ASP TextBox extra values after postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In summary: I'm saving grid id and row number to some hidden textboxes inside a GridView so I can update the session data via jQuery.  After a drag and drop operation on the GridView, one of the textboxes holds different data than it should.  Does anyone know why this might be?

Edit: solved by doing the databinding in Page_PreRender instead of Page_Load.

I'm trying to build a page with 2 draggable and sortable GridViews.  This is a 'teach myself jQuery in preparation for using those methods on production pages' kind of project.  When a row is dragged and dropped, it calls a postback to update the underlying datasets and rebind the grids.  Users should be able to reorder the gridviews and also drag rows from one to the other.  I get the feeling that I'm making it way harder than it should be, but that's not my question.

To make the postbacks work, I'm creating 2 hidden textboxes that store the grid id and row number on each row.  jQuery uses those as parameters to pass to the code-behind via a PageMethods call.  All of that works, the first time.

If I try to do a drag-and-drop on a row I already dragged and dropped once, the row number textbox.text field becomes x,x instead of x like the other rows.  For instance, dragging row 1 somewhere makes row 1's TextBox.Text become 1,1.  I've verified that in RowDataBound the number is 1 and at Page_Unload it's 1,1.  Why is this?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        stack: ".draggable",
        snapto: ".droppable",
        create: function(event, ui){
            var GridID = $(this).find(".gridid").attr("value");
            $(this).data("source",GridID);  
            var RowID = $(this).find(".rowindex").attr("value");
            $(this).data("rowid",RowID);  
        }
    });
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        tolerance: "intersect",
        greedy: true,
        create: function(event, ui){
            var GridID = $(this).find(".gridid").attr("value");
            $(this).data("source",GridID);  
            var RowID = $(this).find(".rowindex").attr("value");
            $(this).data("rowid",RowID); 
        },
        drop: function(event, ui){
            var SourceGrid = ui.draggable.data("source");
            var SourceRow = ui.draggable.data("rowid");
            var DestGrid = $(this).data("source");
            var DestRow = $(this).data("rowid");
            PageMethods.MoveRow(SourceGrid, DestGrid, SourceRow, DestRow);
            __doPostBack('','');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

ASP:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMain" runat="Server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvSource" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" 
    OnRowDataBound="gvSource_RowDataBound">
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvDest" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
    OnRowDataBound="gvSource_RowDataBound">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code-Behind (minus the DataBinding and fetching parts):

```
protected void gvSource_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    TextBox gridid = new TextBox();
    gridid.Text = ((GridView)sender).ClientID;
    gridid.CssClass = "gridid hidden";
    TextBox rowindex = new TextBox();
    switch (e.Row.RowType) {
        case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
            rowindex.Text = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
            break;
        case DataControlRowType.Header:
            rowindex.Text = "0";
            break;
        case DataControlRowType.Footer:
            rowindex.Text = ((DataTable)((GridView)sender).DataSource).Rows.Count.ToString();
            break;
        default:
            rowindex.Text = "null";
            break;
    }
    rowindex.CssClass = "rowindex hidden";
    e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(gridid);
    e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(rowindex);
}
[WebMethod]
public static string MoveRow(string _sourcegrid, string _destgrid, string _sourcerow, string _destrow) {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        DataTable dtsrc = _sourcegrid == ((DataTable)ctx.Session["dtFrom"]).TableName ? (DataTable)ctx.Session["dtFrom"] : (DataTable)ctx.Session["dtTo"];
        DataTable dtdest = _destgrid == ((DataTable)ctx.Session["dtFrom"]).TableName ? (DataTable)ctx.Session["dtFrom"] : (DataTable)ctx.Session["dtTo"];
        DataRow row = dtsrc.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(_sourcerow)];
        DataRow newrow = dtdest.NewRow();
        int newrowpos = Convert.ToInt32(_destrow);
        newrow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
        dtsrc.Rows.Remove(row);
        dtdest.Rows.InsertAt(newrow, newrowpos);
        return "1";
}
```

CSS-wise, all rows have CssClass="droppable draggable".  Headers and footers are just droppable.  I left off some error checking code for brevity.

edit: added a summary, and I wanted to add that I've looked through SO and found only topics about a TextBox losing its data, not changing it.

Comment: Hi & welcome to stack! Reviewing your question it is a bit difficult to understand what you are asking. When you post questions in the future try to be really clear about what you are asking - maybe even put the question before all of the background + code. Just a thought!

Comment: Can you post all code that references the TextBox in .aspx, .cs and javascript.

Comment: gbs: The TextBox is not referenced anywhere else besides the RowDataBound event and the Create events of the draggable and droppable objects, which I listed.

Comment: drew: thanks for the advice.  I put a shorter summation and question at the top.

Comment: Did some more checking and it looks like the TextBox value is getting changed somewhere between the end of Page_Load and the start of Page_LoadComplete.  Turning ViewState on or off doesn't affect it.  Time to learn more about the stuff that happens in the background during those times.

Comment: Finally found it.  Calling the GridView.DataBind() methods in Page_PreRender instead of Page_Load makes the problem go away, though I'm still not sure why.  Whatever, it's a solution that works.

Comment: Hey, Mike.  I'm glad you found a solution to your problem, and that you responded constructively and quickly to comments.  FYI - you can [post an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  That is the usual way for closing out questions you've solved yourself (rather than just updating your original post).

Comment: Also: since moving your datanding to PreRender worked, I'm curious - did you have your databinding code in a `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` block when it was in Page_Load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had something to do with binding the data in Page_Load.  It looked like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        GetData(); //Database fetch saves 2 DataTables to session variables
    }
    gvSource.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["dtFrom"];
    gvSource.DataBind();
    gvDest.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["dtTo"];
    gvDest.DataBind();
}
```

and it failed.  Made it

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        GetData();  //Database fetch
    }
}
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    gvSource.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["dtFrom"];
    gvSource.DataBind();
    gvDest.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["dtTo"];
    gvDest.DataBind();
}
```

and it worked.  Why it worked is still open for debate.  Thanks guys for helping this long-time lurker with basic SO usage and etiquette.

Comment: The problem seems to be from GV databinding on each PageLoad. You should have put your databiding inside if(!IsPostBack) block.